# CFQL Search method using an OR expression among multiple properties

Tags: codefluent

I'm trying to ellaborate a SEARCH CFQL method.

I have either a property *TownId* set or a property *TownLabel* in the entity **Address**:

- *TownId* is set if the address got affected a **Town** from a referential (Towns are stored in another DB and are referenced only by ID).
- *TownLabel* is set if none of the known Towns was found. (e.g. Name of a town abroad)

In my SEARCH method I want to look for users having as a town, either the townLabel OR possible towns from the referential whoes name contains the value townLabel.

Long story short, my CFQL methods is as follow

```
SEARCH(string[] townIds, string townLabel) WHERE Adresses.TownId IN (@townIds) OR Adresses.TownLabel LIKE '%'+@townLabel+'%'
```

Despite the OR operator, the generated SQL appears with the AND operator as below.

**My question**: is it normal ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_AdvancedSearch]
(
 @townIds [nvarchar] (max) = NULL,
 @townLabel [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @_orderBy0 [nvarchar] (64) = NULL,
 @_orderByDirection0 [bit] = 0
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @paramlist nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql=
'SELECT DISTINCT [User].[User_UserId], [User].[User_Name], [User].[User_Association_AssociationId], [User].[_trackLastWriteTime], [User].[_trackCreationTime], [User].[_trackLastWriteUser], [User].[_trackCreationUser], [User].[_rowVersion] 
    FROM [User]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] ON ([User].[User_UserId] = [Address].[Address_User_UserId])
    WHERE ((1 = 1) AND (1 = 1))'
SELECT @paramlist = '@townIds nvarchar (max), 
    @townLabel nvarchar (256), 
    @_orderBy0 nvarchar (64), 
    @_orderByDirection0 bit'
IF @townIds IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ([Address].[Address_TownId] IN ((SELECT [Item] FROM [dbo].cf_SplitString(@townIds, nchar(1)))))'
IF @townLabel IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Address].[Address_TownLabel] LIKE ((''%'' + @townLabel) + ''%'')))'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,
    @townIds, 
    @townLabel, 
    @_orderBy0, 
    @_orderByDirection0

RETURN
GO
```

The schema is given below

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="WcfServices.Model" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1" xmlns:cfom="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.model/2005/1" xmlns:cfsps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlpivotscript/2013/1" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:entity name="Association" namespace="Example.Model.Association" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="AssociationId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Label" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Users" typeName="Example.Model.Association.UserCollection" relationPropertyName="Association" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration produceViews="true" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.persistence" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.persistence\WcfServices.persistence.sqlproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update, DontRemove" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer name="Business Object Model (BOM)" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom">
    <cf:configuration compileWithVisualStudio="true" compile="false" codeDomProviderTypeName="CSharp" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.model" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.model\WcfServices.model.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update">
    </cf:configuration>
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="User" namespace="Example.Model.Association" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="UserId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Name" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Association" typeName="Example.Model.Association.Association" relationPropertyName="Users" />
    <cf:property name="Adresses" typeName="Example.Model.Association.AddressCollection" relationPropertyName="User" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:method name="AdvancedSearch" body="SEARCH(string[] townIds, string townLabel) WHERE Adresses.TownId IN (@townIds) OR Adresses.TownLabel LIKE '%%'+@townLabel+'%%'" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server Pivot Script" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlPivotScriptProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.web" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.web\WcfServices.web.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="Address" namespace="Example.Model.Association" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="AddressId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Line" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="User" typeName="Example.Model.Association.User" relationPropertyName="Adresses" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="TownLabel" />
    <cf:property name="TownId" typeName="guid" />
  </cf:entity>
</cf:project>
```

EDIT 15/09/2016 - adding original CFQL + schema.

Original CFQL method:

```
SEARCH (string firstname, string name, int[] groups, string postalCode, string townLabel, string mail, string[] townId, guid structureId, guid countryId) WHERE Firstname LIKE '%'+@firstname+'%' AND Name LIKE '%'+@name+'%' AND (Address.PostalCode LIKE '%'+@postalCode+'%' OR StructureContacts.Address.PostalCode LIKE '%'+@postalCode+'%') AND ( Address.TownLabel LIKE '%'+@townLabel+'%' OR StructureContacts.Address.TownLabel LIKE '%'+@townLabel+'%' OR Address.TownId IN (@townId) OR StructureContacts.Address.TownId IN(@townId)) AND (StructureContacts.Groups.Value IN (@groups) OR Groups.Value IN (@groups)) AND StructureContacts.Structure.StructureId = @structureId and (Address.Email LIKE '%'+@mail+'%' OR StructureContacts.Address.Email LIKE '%'+@mail+'%') AND (Address.CountryId = @countryId OR StructureContacts.Address.CountryId = @countryId) order by Name, Firstname
```

Schema:

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="Example.Models" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1">
  <cf:enumeration name="enumStructureType" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/RH">
    <cf:enumerationValue name="ENTERPRISE" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="ASSOCIATION" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="OTHER_ASSOCIATION" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="SUPPLIER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="PUBLIC_ORGANIZATION" />
  </cf:enumeration>
  <cf:entity name="Structure" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" defaultPersistenceEnforce="false" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/RH" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="StructureId" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="Sigle" />
    <cf:property name="CorporateName" />
    <cf:property name="Code" />
    <cf:property name="Comment">
      <cf:rule typeName="StringValidate" maxLength="2000" />
    </cf:property>
    <cf:property name="Siret" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" collectionKey="false">
      <cf:rule typeName="RegularExpressionValidate" expression="[\d]{14,14}" />
    </cf:property>
    <cf:property name="Type" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" defaultValue="EstablishmentType.PRINCIPAL" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.enumStructureType" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="Groups" set="true" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.GroupCollection" />
    <cf:property name="ApeId" typeName="guid" />
    <cf:property name="Address" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.Address" relationSchema="Contact" />
    <cf:property name="EstablishmentType" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.enumEstablishmentType" />
    <cf:property name="ParentStructure" readOnSave="true" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.Structure" relationPropertyName="ChildrenStructures" />
    <cf:property name="ChildrenStructures" set="true" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.StructureCollection" relationPropertyName="ParentStructure" />
    <cf:property name="OpeningHours" maxLength="2000" />
    <cf:method name="SimpleSearchStructures" body="SEARCH (string keyword) WHERE CorporateName LIKE '%%'+@keyword+'%%' OR Code LIKE '%%'+@keyword+'%%' OR Comment LIKE '%%'+@keyword+'%%' OR Sigle LIKE '%%'+@keyword+'%%' OR Siret LIKE '%%'+@keyword+'%%' OR Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@keyword+'%%' ORDER BY CorporateName" />
    <cf:method name="AdvancedSearchStructures" body="SEARCH (string corporateName, string email, string postalCode, string townLabel, string[] townIds, int[] groups, guid countryId, int[] types) WHERE CorporateName LIKE '%%'+@corporateName+'%%' AND Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@email+'%%'  AND (Address.TownLabel LIKE '%%'+@townLabel+'%%' OR Address.TownId IN (@townIds)) AND Address.PostalCode LIKE '%%'+@postalCode+'%%' AND Address.CountryId = @countryId AND Groups.Value IN (@groups) AND Type IN (@types) ORDER BY CorporateName" />
    <cf:rule typeName="OnBeforeSave" methodName="BeforeSave" />
    <cf:method name="DeleteById" body="DELETE(guid id) WHERE StructureId = @id" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="StructureAssociation" baseTypeName="Example.Models.Contact.Structure.Structure" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="ParutionDateOJ" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="BasinId" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" typeName="guid" relationSchema="Contact" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="ReceiptNum" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="PrefectureId" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="CreationDate" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="CartePecheAappmaId" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:method name="LoadAssociationStructure" body="LOADONE WHERE EstablishmentType = 3" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="StructureContact" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" setType="List" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/RH" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="Function" defaultValue="enumFunctionType.PRESIDENT" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.enumFunctionType" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="StartDateFunction" usePersistenceDefaultValue="true" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="EndDateFunction" usePersistenceDefaultValue="true" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="Contact" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.Contact" relationPropertyName="StructureContacts" relationSchema="Contact" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Address" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.Address" relationSchema="Contact" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Groups" set="true" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.GroupCollection" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DocumentUrl" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Structure" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.Structure" persistenceEnforce="true">
      <cf:attribute name="Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore" class="" />
    </cf:property>
    <cf:property name="StructureContactId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="AdditionalDate" usePersistenceDefaultValue="true" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DocumentName" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:method name="LoadBoardMembers" body="LOAD (int[] functions) WHERE Function IN (@functions)" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="StructureEnterprise" baseTypeName="Example.Models.Contact.Structure.Structure" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="VATNum" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="StructureOtherAssociation" baseTypeName="Example.Models.Contact.Structure.Structure" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="ReceiptNum" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" persistenceEnforce="true" collectionKey="false" />
    <cf:property name="SkillTerritoryType" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.enumStructureSkillTerritoryType" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Address" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Contact" categoryPath="/RH" persistenceName="Address" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="AddressId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Line1" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Line2" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="IsActive" typeName="bool" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Landline" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Email" persistenceEnforce="true">
      <cf:rule typeName="EmailValidate" />
    </cf:property>
    <cf:property name="Fax" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Website" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Mobile" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DirectLine" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="ProfessionalLine" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="TownId" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="TownLabel" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="CountryId" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="PostalCode" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:rule typeName="OnBeforeSave" methodName="BeforeSave" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Contact" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Contact" categoryPath="/RH" persistenceName="Contact" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="Name" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Firstname" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Civility" defaultValue="CivilityContact.Mr" typeName="{0}.Global.Civility" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DateOfBirth" serializationNullable="true" modelNullable="true" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Comment" persistenceEnforce="true">
      <cf:rule typeName="StringValidate" maxLength="2000" />
    </cf:property>
    <cf:property name="ContactId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="StructureContacts" set="true" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Structure.StructureContactCollection" relationPropertyName="Contact" relationSchema="Contact" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Address" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.Address" relationSchema="Contact" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="TownOfBirthLabel" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="TownIdOfBirth" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="CountryIdOfBirth" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DepartmentIdOfBirth" typeName="guid" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="PostalCode" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Groups" set="true" cascadeSave="After" cascadeDelete="Before" typeName="{0}.Contact.Contact.GroupCollection" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="CartePecheMemberId" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:method name="AdvancedSearchContactsTownLabel" body="SEARCH (string firstname, string name, int[] groups, string postalCode, string townLabel, string mail, string[] townId, guid structureId, guid countryId) WHERE Firstname LIKE '%%'+@firstname+'%%' AND Name LIKE '%%'+@name+'%%' AND (Address.PostalCode LIKE '%%'+@postalCode+'%%' OR StructureContacts.Address.PostalCode LIKE '%%'+@postalCode+'%%') AND ( Address.TownLabel LIKE '%%'+@townLabel+'%%' OR StructureContacts.Address.TownLabel LIKE '%%'+@townLabel+'%%' OR Address.TownId IN (@townId) OR StructureContacts.Address.TownId IN(@townId)) AND (StructureContacts.Groups.Value IN (@groups) OR Groups.Value IN (@groups)) AND StructureContacts.Structure.StructureId = @structureId and (Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@mail+'%%' OR StructureContacts.Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@mail+'%%') AND (Address.CountryId = @countryId OR StructureContacts.Address.CountryId = @countryId) order by Name, Firstname" />
    <cf:method name="SimpleSearchContacts" body="SEARCH(string keywords) WHERE Firstname LIKE '%%'+@keywords+'%%' OR Name LIKE '%%'+@keywords+'%%' OR Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@keywords+'%%' OR StructureContacts.Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@keywords+'%%' order by Name, Firstname" />
    <cf:rule typeName="OnBeforeSave" methodName="BeforeSave" />
    <cf:method name="SearchContactByName" body="SEARCH(string nameOrFirstName, int[] functions) WHERE (Name LIKE '%%'+@nameOrFirstName+'%%' OR Firstname LIKE '%%'+@nameOrFirstName+'%%') AND StructureContacts.Function IN (@functions)" />
    <cf:method name="LoadContactsByDateFunction" body="LOAD (date currentDate, int[] functions) WHERE StructureContacts.Function IN (@functions) AND ( StructureContacts.StartDateFunction &lt;= @currentDate OR NOT StructureContacts.StartDateFunction EXISTS )&#xD;&#xA; AND ( StructureContacts.EndDateFunction &gt; @currentDate OR NOT StructureContacts.EndDateFunction EXISTS )" />
    <cf:method name="DeleteById" body="DELETE(guid id) WHERE ContactId = @id" />
    <cf:method name="AdvancedSearchContactTownId" body="SEARCH (string firstname, string name, int[] groups, string postalCode, string townLabel, string mail, string[] townId, guid structureId, guid countryId) WHERE Firstname LIKE '%%'+@firstname+'%%' AND Name LIKE '%%'+@name+'%%' AND (Address.PostalCode LIKE '%%'+@postalCode+'%%' OR StructureContacts.Address.PostalCode LIKE '%%'+@postalCode+'%%')  AND (Address.TownId IN (@townId) OR StructureContacts.Address.TownId IN(@townId) ) AND (StructureContacts.Groups.Value IN (@groups) OR Groups.Value IN (@groups)) AND StructureContacts.Structure.StructureId = @structureId and (Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@mail+'%%' OR StructureContacts.Address.Email LIKE '%%'+@mail+'%%') AND (Address.CountryId = @countryId OR StructureContacts.Address.CountryId = @countryId) order by Name, Firstname" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Group" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Contact" categoryPath="/RH" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="GroupId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Value" defaultValue="enumGroupType.DGS" typeName="int" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="StructureSupplier" baseTypeName="Example.Models.Contact.Structure.Structure" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="CartePecheDepositaireId" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="NumberExt" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DocumentUrl" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="DocumentName" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="IsKeyAccount" typeName="bool" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="ConventionDate" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:enumeration name="enumEstablishmentType" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models">
    <cf:enumerationValue name="HEAD_OFFICE" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="SECONDARY" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="DELEGATION" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="ASSOCIATION" />
  </cf:enumeration>
  <cf:enumeration name="enumFunctionType" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models">
    <cf:enumerationValue name="DIRECTOR" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="EMPLOYEE" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="ELECTED" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="VOLUNTEER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="INDIVIDUAL" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="PRESIDENT" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="VICE_PRESIDENT" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="TREASURER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="SECRETARY" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="BOARD_MEMBER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="LEGAL_MEMBER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="BY_LAW_MEMBER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="ACCOUNT_INSPECTOR" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="RESELLER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="OWNER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="CONTRACTOR" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="GENERAL_CONTRACTOR" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="CONTRACTING_AUTHORITY" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="LESSOR" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="OTHER" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="MEMBER" />
  </cf:enumeration>
  <cf:enumeration name="enumStructureSkillTerritoryType" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models">
    <cf:enumerationValue name="LOCAL" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="DEPARTEMENTAL" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="REGIONAL" />
    <cf:enumerationValue name="NATIONAL" />
  </cf:enumeration>
  <cf:entity name="StructurePublicOrganization" baseTypeName="Example.Models.Contact.Structure.Structure" namespace="Example.Models.Contact.Structure" categoryPath="/Example.Models" storeName="ExampleStoreName">
    <cf:property name="ReceiptNum" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
</cf:project>
```

The generated SQL (note the extra AND in townLabel parameter)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Contact].[Contact_AdvancedSearchContactsTownLabel]
(
 @firstname [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @name [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @groups [Contact].[cf_type_Contact_AdvancedSearchContactsTownLabel_2] READONLY,
 @postalCode [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @townLabel [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @mail [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @townId [nvarchar] (max) = NULL,
 @structureId [uniqueidentifier] = NULL,
 @countryId [uniqueidentifier] = NULL,
 @_orderBy0 [nvarchar] (64) = NULL,
 @_orderByDirection0 [bit] = 0
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @_c_groups int; SELECT @_c_groups= COUNT(*) FROM @groups
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @paramlist nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql=
'SELECT DISTINCT [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Name], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Firstname], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Civility], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_DateOfBirth], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Comment], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_ContactId], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Address_AddressId], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_TownOfBirthLabel], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_TownIdOfBirth], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_CountryIdOfBirth], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_DepartmentIdOfBirth], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_PostalCode], [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_CartePecheMemberId], [Contact].[Contact].[_trackLastWriteTime], [Contact].[Contact].[_trackCreationTime], [Contact].[Contact].[_trackLastWriteUser], [Contact].[Contact].[_trackCreationUser], [Contact].[Contact].[_rowVersion] 
    FROM [Contact].[Contact]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Address] ON ([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Address_AddressId] = [Contact].[Address].[Address_AddressId])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[StructureContact] ON ([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_ContactId] = [Contact].[StructureContact].[StructureContact_Contact_ContactId])
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Address] [Address$1] ON ([Contact].[StructureContact].[StructureContact_Address_AddressId] = [Address$1].[Address_AddressId])
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[StructureContact_Groups_Group] ON ([Contact].[StructureContact].[StructureContact_StructureContactId] = [Contact].[StructureContact_Groups_Group].[StructureContact_StructureContactId])
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Group] ON ([Contact].[StructureContact_Groups_Group].[Group_GroupId] = [Contact].[Group].[Group_GroupId])
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Structure] ON ([Contact].[StructureContact].[StructureContact_Structure_StructureId] = [Contact].[Structure].[Structure_StructureId])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Address] [Address$2] ON ([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Address_AddressId] = [Address$2].[Address_AddressId])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Contact_Groups_Group] ON ([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_ContactId] = [Contact].[Contact_Groups_Group].[Contact_ContactId])
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Group] [Group$1] ON ([Contact].[Contact_Groups_Group].[Group_GroupId] = [Group$1].[Group_GroupId])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contact].[Address] [Address$3] ON ([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Address_AddressId] = [Address$3].[Address_AddressId]) 
    WHERE (((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND (1 = 1)))))))) AND (1 = 1))'
SELECT @paramlist = '@firstname nvarchar (256), 
    @name nvarchar (256), 
    @groups [Contact].[cf_type_Contact_AdvancedSearchContactsTownLabel_2] READONLY, 
    @postalCode nvarchar (256), 
    @townLabel nvarchar (256), 
    @mail nvarchar (256), 
    @townId nvarchar (max), 
    @structureId uniqueidentifier, 
    @countryId uniqueidentifier, 
    @_orderBy0 nvarchar (64), 
    @_orderByDirection0 bit'
IF @firstname IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Firstname] LIKE ((''%'' + @firstname) + ''%'')))'
IF @name IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Name] LIKE ((''%'' + @name) + ''%'')))'
IF @_c_groups > 0
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Contact].[Group].[Group_Value] IN ((SELECT * FROM @groups)) OR [Group$1].[Group_Value] IN ((SELECT * FROM @groups))))'
IF @postalCode IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ((([Contact].[Address].[Address_PostalCode] LIKE ((''%'' + @postalCode) + ''%'')) OR ([Address$1].[Address_PostalCode] LIKE ((''%'' + @postalCode) + ''%''))))'
IF @townLabel IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ((([Address$2].[Address_TownLabel] LIKE ((''%'' + @townLabel) + ''%'')) OR (([Contact].[Address].[Address_TownLabel] LIKE ((''%'' + @townLabel) + ''%'')) OR ([Contact].[Address].[Address_TownId] IN ((SELECT [Item] FROM [dbo].cf_SplitString(@townId, nchar(1)))) OR [Contact].[Address].[Address_TownId] IN ((SELECT [Item] FROM [dbo].cf_SplitString(@townId, nchar(1))))))) AND ([Contact].[Address].[Address_TownLabel] LIKE ((''%'' + @townLabel) + ''%'')))'
IF @mail IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ((([Address$3].[Address_Email] LIKE ((''%'' + @mail) + ''%'')) OR ([Contact].[Address].[Address_Email] LIKE ((''%'' + @mail) + ''%''))))'
IF @townId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Contact].[Address].[Address_TownId] IN ((SELECT [Item] FROM [dbo].cf_SplitString(@townId, nchar(1)))) OR [Contact].[Address].[Address_TownId] IN ((SELECT [Item] FROM [dbo].cf_SplitString(@townId, nchar(1))))))'
IF @structureId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Contact].[Structure].[Structure_StructureId] = @structureId))'
IF @countryId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ((([Contact].[Address].[Address_CountryId] = @countryId) OR ([Contact].[Address].[Address_CountryId] = @countryId)))'
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY [Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Name] ASC,[Contact].[Contact].[Contact_Firstname] ASC'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,
    @firstname, 
    @name, 
    @groups, 
    @postalCode, 
    @townLabel, 
    @mail, 
    @townId, 
    @structureId, 
    @countryId, 
    @_orderBy0, 
    @_orderByDirection0

RETURN
GO
```

EDIT 16/09/2016-possible workarounds found.

I found two possible workarounds:

- First is to have a simpler search method with the rest of parameters (no townId, no townLabel), and to re-filter in memory with a LINQ mechanism.
- Second is to go use generated code in a RAW method and adapt it to make it work the way we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Search` methods are very tricky to generate. In fact, the producer must split the body of the method by parameters. Then it creates `IF @param IS NOT NULL` statement and combine them using an operator (by default `AND`). If you want to change this operator, you can add the following xml attribute at the method:

```
<cf:method cfps:searchOperation="OR" ... />
```

If you don't have too many arguments (1 or 2) you can use a LOAD method with nullable parameters:

```
<cf:method name="LoadNullable" body="LOAD(string text1, string text2) WHERE Name = @text1 AND Name = @text2">
  <cf:parameter nullable="True" name="text1" modelNullable="False" />
</cf:method>
```

The generated code looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_LoadNullable]
(
 @text1 [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @text2 [nvarchar] (256)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF(@text1 IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT [Customer].[Customer_Id], [Customer].[Customer_Name]
        FROM [Customer] 
        WHERE ([Customer].[Customer_Name] = @text2)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT [Customer].[Customer_Id], [Customer].[Customer_Name]
        FROM [Customer] 
        WHERE (([Customer].[Customer_Name] = @text1) AND ([Customer].[Customer_Name] = @text2))
END
```

This way you don't have any issue with the `OR` and `AND`, but this is not suitable for methods with many nullable parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately if I have a bunch of merely 10 nullables parameters, only 2 of them are part of an OR operation. How come parenthesis are not of any help ?

Comment: Can you add the full CFQL method to your question?

Comment: I edited my question to attach original CFQL method, schema and generated SQL procedure. The schema is more complicated than the example given.